# MySQLi GET, FROM and WHERE

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to `GET user id FROM players WHERE username='$username'` and post it into another `MySQLi` query and post it as pid but it shows error somehow, did I miss something?

```
if(isset($_POST["add"])) {
  $content = $_POST['content'];
  $sql = "SELECT id FROM players WHERE username='$username'";
  $sql1 = "INSERT INTO bulletinboard (pid,content) VALUES ('$sql','$content')"; 

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql1)) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }  
}
```

This is the error I am receiving.

```
Error: SELECT id FROM players WHERE username='nasty93'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to execute the query so it needs to not be quoted. You also should familiarize yourself with the `insert...select` syntax. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html

You also should use parameterized queries. Here it is altered (untested) (I also only use `mysqli` on SO so likely to be an error here).

```
if(isset($_POST["add"])) {
     $content = $_POST['content'];
     $sql1 = "INSERT INTO bulletinboard (pid,content) SELECT id, ? FROM players WHERE username=?"; 
     $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql1) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
     mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $content, $username) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
     mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
}
```